# Background image in Outlook - unknown height?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013

I set a background image via:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td background="my-bg.jpg" bgcolor="#ebeae8" valign="top">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="my-bg.jpg" color="#ebeae8" />
             <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                   <div>
                       CONTENT HERE
                    </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
.....more content that gets overlayed in Outlook 2013
```

Unfortunately in Outlook 2013 this overlays other content below it in the email. With some testing I presume this is due to not setting a height on the v:rect.

1. How can I set a height on the v-rect so it's the height of its contents.

OR

2. How can I prevent the above td with a background image overlaying conetnt after it?

Comment: DO you mean that next table is supposed to overlay the first?

Comment: No overlay, the following table should sit below the table with the background.

Answer (score -3):

You can set a height of your `v:rect` element in the code:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td background="my-bg.jpg" bgcolor="#ebeae8" valign="top">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px; height:100px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="my-bg.jpg" color="#ebeae8" />
             <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                   <div>
                       CONTENT HERE
                     </div>
                     <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                     </v:textbox>
                     </v:rect>
                     <![endif]-->
        </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
```

But I think maybe the problem comes from the image size, you CAN specify a different image just for Outlook. I ran into this problem and noticed that the tiling can push content down if you are using the same image bg as the rest of the code.

Comment: I know I can specify the height - the issue is I do not know the height of the content.

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100%`? Or specify the height as a maximum you think it's going to be? For instance, for 600px, chances are it will be 400px or 450px.

Comment: If you have a direct path to the image, you should be able to ascertain the height. Or make the BG image a bit longer than the possible height of the content.

Comment: I don't think you get it. The bg should be the height of the content - the height of the content is unknown.

Comment: There's no way to do that then. You cannot code a specific height for what is unknown.